# Easier way to share xlsx file with side-loaded add-ins

Tags: office-js

We are in the process of developing several add-ins.  Whie we are developing we typically create xlsx files to demo our progress and share it amongst our co-workers.  We have followed the guide on how to side-load the add-ins ([here](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins#specify-the-shared-folder-as-a-trusted-catalog)) on all the machines. The problem comes in when we share those xlsx files. Since our network paths to the manifests aren't exactly the same (i.e. `//MACHINE1/manifests` vs `//ANOTHER_MACHINE/manifests`), Excel will complain about the add-in when it is opened on another machine.

We have alleviated some of these issues by using a network path of `//localhost/c$/manifest` in the trusted catalog area, and just make sure all people have their manifests in `C:\manifest`, that way we don't need to tweak the xlsx file for each machine that is using it.

So, I guess my question is: **Is there a way to remove this network path restriction from the xlsx file, so users can put the manifest files wherever they want**?

*Additional Info*: We went the local shared folder route, because we did not have easy access to a sharepoint server, and trying to use Azure as a network share ran into issues, cause some of our ISPs blocked the ports necessary to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Our recommended approach for deploying Add-Ins is to use the Centralized Deployment feature which is currently in preview https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Deploy-Office-Add-ins-in-the-Office-365-Admin-Center-737e8c86-be63-44d7-bf02-492fa7cd9c3f

However in your situation I'd recommend creating a network share where users can drop Add-Ins and setting that as your shared folder. That should eliminate the issues you describe